# How to notify the user to enable gpsprovider

Tags: android

i'm working on gpsprovider,If user click on a gps based applications for suppose map application it has check whether the gps provider enabled or not if not alert the user enable the gpsprovider .

There will be a Broadcast Receivier. 
Will define a message for requesting the service from any application. Will start service if not started. 
Will define a message for stating that the application no longer needs it. Will stop service if no app needs it anymore

Answer (score 4):

```
  String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),     Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(provider != null ){      
        if(! provider.contains("gps")){    
            // Notify users and show settings if they want to enable GPS
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MessagePage.this)
            .setMessage("GPS is switched off. enable?")
            .setPositiveButton("Enable GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Don't do it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .show();
        }
    }
```

---

```
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
       if(requestCode == 5 && resultCode == 0){
           String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
           if(provider != null){
               switch(provider.length()){
               case 0:                     
                    //GPS still not enabled..
                   break;
               default:
                   Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is now enabled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       else{
           //the user did not enable his GPS
       }
}
```

Comment: Actually i'm able to enable the gps within the application.but,i'm looking for the solution which would enable the gps or alert the user when  any of the gps based application is used.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is still not possible to start the GPS service programatically. The only thing you can do is open the settings page for the user to change the setting them selves:

```
if(!LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )) 
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS ); startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: Nor should it be possible for an app to programatically turn this on: that could present users with serious security and privacy risks.

Answer (score 0):

**In your CommonUtils.java**

```
public class CommonUtils {
public static void displayPromptForEnablingGPS(
        final Activity activity)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;
    final String message = "Enable either GPS or any other location"
            + " service to find current location.  Click OK to go to"
            + " location services settings to let you do so.";

    builder.setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                            activity.startActivity(new Intent(action));
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                            d.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    builder.create().show();
}
```

}

**In your activity**

```
private void getGPSInfo() {

    LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    // YOUR MAPS ACTIVITY CALLING or WHAT YOU NEED

    } else {
        CommonUtils.displayPromptForEnablingGPS(getActivity());
    }
}
```